# web design 101: how do i get my links to work with pages in my website

Tags: html

I'm new to html5 coding. I'm looking for the instructions for adding pages to your website. Does anyone know of a good website that explains it?

As far as I can tell i think it has something to do with links but I understand how you go from links a page to linking "your" page in the website. I found this example online:

```
  <div id="page">
    <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
    <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">About</a> 
</div>
    <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Benefits</a></div>
    <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Services</a></div>
    <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Contact</a> .   </div>
  </div>
```

I have not used "topNaviagation" before but I've href=" to specify my link.

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: https://en.ryte.com/wiki/Anchor_Tag

Answer (score 2):

```
class="topNaviagationLink" mean the class of CSS
```

if you want to link Another page of your web site simple use this structure

```
 <a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a>
```

**You can change *about.html*** add your page name with .html

**target attribute ** is how to open that link

**Examples**

**_blank** -->  Opens the linked document in a new window or tab 
**_self**  -->  Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
**_parent** --> Opens the linked document in the parent frame 
**_top**    --> Opens the linked document in the full body of the window